# Laravel SMTP settings are not working but the same settings are working in Perl

Tags: laravel, perl, email, smtp

I'm having troubles with SMTP settings in my Laravel.

Here is the mail section of in my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=xxxxx.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=yyyyy.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I'm getting next error:

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host xxxxx.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://xxxxx.com:25 (Permission denied)
```

I've also tried ports 587 and 465. The same result.

But simple Perl script with the same auth data is working correctly:

```
$To = 'example@xxx.com';
$Server = 'xxxxx.com';
$From = '"Do Not Reply" <donotreply@xxx.com>';
$ReplyTo = '"Do Not Reply" <donotreply@xxx.com>';
$Invitation = "test.txt";
$smtp = Net::SMTP->new($Server, Hello => 'yyyyy.com', Timeout => 30, Debug => 1,);
$smtp->mail($From);
$smtp->to($To);
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: $To\n");
$smtp->datasend("From: $From\n");
$smtp->datasend("Reply-To: $ReplyTo\n");
open(INVITE, "<$Invitation") || die "Cannot open invitation: $!\n";
while(<INVITE>) {
  $smtp->datasend($_);
}
$smtp->dataend();
close INVITE;
$smtp->quit;
```

My only doubt is that Hello option in Perl script and MAIL_USERNAME in .env file is not the same option.

Maybe I should use other option for that in my .env file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem wasn't in Laravel settings or in Pearl Hello option. It was in certain server setting.

I had to run

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

on server and everything started to work.

I still have no idea why Perl script was working just fine without that setting but it not that important.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the MAIL_PORT to 587

Comment: thank you for suggestion, but there is same result. I've also tried 465 port. No success. I've updated my post.

Comment: Ah ok, What I normally do to test my STMP settings is download Mozilla Thunderbird and see which settings work on there and apply the same one onto the app.